# Wordpress update user meta when the user submits form (form called with do_shortcode)

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, usermetadata

I want to update user meta after the user submits a form. `function updateUserType(){update_user_meta` works as expected alone, however it does not work when the form is called with `do_shortcode`.

```
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="031c4e8" title="Dosya"]');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'updateUserType');
function updateUserType() {
    $user_idd = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $user_idd, '_user_type', 'general' ) ;}
```

Comment: _Where_ are those codes located?

Comment: It's inside some plugin file.

Comment: This is likely going to be a problem of execution order in one way or another. Have you tried putting the `do_shortcode` call _after_ the `add_action` call?

Comment: Yes I tried all combinations of execution order for the `do_shortcode`, `add_action` and `function`

Comment: The function definitely does not being called.
I tried `add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', update_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_type', 'general' ) );` and this executes `update_user_meta` as soon as the page loads.

Comment: _"and this executes update_user_meta as soon as the page loads"_ - of course, because you are not passing a _callback_ function to `add_action` with this syntax, but you are _executing_ `update_user_meta` right in that place there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the CF7 Meta field 'current_user_id' would return the user id whether it's called via `do_shortcode` or otherwise. You could add a 'subscriber_mode:on' to the extra settings in the form to prevent non-logged in users from completing the form if you wanted to.

This has been tested and works.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dd_update_user_type', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Update user type in user metadata.
 *
 * @param object $contact_form The contact form object.
 * @param bool   $abort        Whether to abort the update or not.
 * @param object $submission   The submission object.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function dd_update_user_type( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    $user_id = $submission->get_meta( 'current_user_id' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_type', 'general' );
}
```